# I can not display the title menu in CSS

Tags: css

The problem is that when I click on the title menu for example "Wohnen" is the bottom tab opens when I turn on this tab, the title "Wohnen" ceases to be ": hover" (Showing different font color and border on the sides). How to make the transition mice on the opening tab, the title was active?

```
/*After hover link show me the menu*/
div#menu a#menu-title:hover + #sub_backbone,
div#menu a#menu-title:hover + #sub_backbone_center,
div#menu a#menu-title:hover + #sub_backbone_end{
    display: block;
}
/*Switching to tab*/
div#menu li #sub_backbone:hover, 
div#menu li #sub_backbone_center:hover, 
div#menu li #sub_backbone_end:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

**Working example is here** http://jsfiddle.net/Tf4fc/

Comment: In this example, I used the CSS / Can you show how this works in JQuery?

Comment: No need for jquery. This can be easily achieved through css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, id's are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't repeat id's. Instead change your id's sub_backbone and menu-title to classes.

Secondly what you want to achieve can be achieved only when you display submenu and menu-header's border on same hover trigger like #menu li:hover

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf4fc/2/)**

```
#menu li:hover #sub_backbone{
    display: block;
}
#menu li:hover #menu-title{

    border-left: 1px solid #E2DAD1;
    border-right: 1px solid #E2DAD1;
    border-top: 1px solid #E2DAD1;
}

#menu li:hover .menu_header{
    color: #f26623;
    background-color: #f0efe6;
}
```

See I triggered all css on #menu li:hover

Comment: Glad to be of help. I do suggest reading on proper HTML syntax.